# Run Python script inside C++ with Python.h

Tags: c++

I'm currently aware of [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/embedding.html) turotial, but I don't see anything in the tutorial that just simply runs a script. If I have a file `pySolve.py` how can I just call it to be executed inside of my code? No input is required as the C++ end generates all files needed before calling the python solve script.

Comment: why don't you use system command to execute that python script?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo what would be the correct calls for running a script in both Linux and Windows? I was hoping for cross compatibility

Comment: it is same in both, you just need to pass the path to the file smartly because in windows the file system is different and for linux we have a different tree structure... I have done something similar where I detect the OS type and based on that I call my system commands..getting it?

Comment: Two suggestions: Firstly, if you just want to execute a script, then embedding a Python interpreter isn't the right choice. Using system() is much easier then. However, if you need to call back and forth between Python and C++, then embedding is the way to go. Secondly, just one hint: If you need to run another script from Python, you just `import` it, which effectively runs it! The only problem might be if the script detects that using the `__name__ == 'main'` stanza. Other than that, see John's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`PyRun_File`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_File) or one of its variants.  And of course first you must call [`Py_Initialize`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Initialize).  You can see example usage of these functions in my open-source project here: https://github.com/jzwinck/pccl/blob/master/run.cpp